# The (change) $event isn't working , maybe syntax problem

Tags: angular

I'm trying to catch any changes in the select tag and activate a function if an option is selected.

html code:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="newProcurement.supplierNumber">
  <option (change)="findSupplierByNumber($event)"  *ngFor="let supplier of 
  allSuppliers" value="{{supplier.suplierName}}">{{supplier.suplierName}} 
  </option>

</select>
```

I'm trying to select a supplier and activate this function:

```
 findSupplierByNumber(ev){
 debugger;
 console.log(ev.target.value)
 }
```

function hasn't been activated for some reason , any suggestions ?

Comment: The `option` doesn't `change`, the `select` does. See the above question for the various choices you have for implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the `change` event to the `select` instead of all the `options`. The `change` event is fired on the `<select>` element whenever an altercation of the value is committed by the user.Change your code to something like this:

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="newProcurement.supplierNumber" (change)="findSupplierByNumber($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let supplier of 
      allSuppliers" value="{{supplier.suplierName}}">{{supplier.suplierName}} 
      </option>
    </select>
```